# Email sending always fails, what is wrong with my contact us code

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am currently working with my Contact Us Page and I have this method:

```
private bool SendEmail()
{

    string subject = SubjectTextBox.Text;
    const string goingTo = "dummie@gmail.com";
    const string smtpUser = "dummie@gmail.com";
    const string smtpPassword = "dummypass";


    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
    smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;


    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();

    mail.To.Add(goingTo);
    mail.From = new MailAddress(smtpUser);
    mail.Subject = subject;
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;

    string collectBody = string.Format("From: {0}<br/>Email: {1}<br/>Contact: {2}<br/><br/><br/><br/>{3}",
                                        NameTextBox.Text, EmailTextBox.Text, ContactTextBox.Text, InquiryTextBox.Text);

    mail.Body = collectBody;
    mail.CC.Add("dummiesekend@gmail.com");

    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";

    smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(smtpUser, smtpPassword);

    try
    {
        smtp.Send(mail);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

in my personal laptop, this works, but in my workplace's laptop, it doesn't. I tried almost all the given codes but it always fails.

Comment: Does it throw the exception? If yes then check the exception message to see what's wrong, otherwise there might be a connection problem in your other laptop?

Comment: it says "Unable to connect to the remote server"

Comment: @mohit, what do you mean? i need to login the dummie gmail? i already did, i even turned on the "Access for less secure apps has been turned on"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Turn off your firewall or disabled antivirus ? If it works, then your firewall or antivirus is blocking something.It may your IP of workplace has blocked for sending mail.

Comment: i don't know but, if a firewall or antivirus is blocking me to send email through the web app, does that mean i couldn't send email through the gmail.com website? because i can still send an email through gmail.com but not through the web app im working

Comment: Alright, I just got a word with my team mate, she said her Contact us Page is also working on her machine, but not in the company's laptop. apparently, it is the company's firewall

Answer (score 1):

use : `using System.Net.Mail;`

Remove Redundant code :

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
```

set that code to be false :

```
smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.EnableSsl = false;
```

check your workspace laptop is install TelnetClient. Turn Windows features on or off in Program and Features..

Answer (score 0):

Raju Mali is right: check your firewall & antivirus configuration. If it works ok locally, contact your local network's administrator: maybe any switch/gateway/router is blocking required port/address.